# Links not highlighting in Android browser after CSS3 transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, android-browser, mobile-webkit

I have the following setup:

```
<div>Element with CSS3 animated height change</div>
<div><a href="#">Link</a></div>
```

I animate the height change of the first element with CSS3 transitions, then I click on the link.  In mobile Safari, the link gets highlighted with a semitransparent overlay, as expected.  In Android browser (tested 2.1, 2.2, 2.3), the link is clickable, but the highlighting doesn't occur.  I can actually usually click and hold on the link's old location and get the tap highlight there.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/DmMZN/

The defect appears to be that Android has a layer of "touch points" corresponding to known element positions, but does not update those points after a CSS3 animation.  Is there any **safe** way to ensure touch points get update correctly?  I am fine with performing a `webkitAnimationEnd` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple enough.  You just need to trigger a DOM change event at the end of the animation.  I'm using the following as it is generic enough not to impact other page elements.

```
function fixTouchLayer() {
    $('<span/>')
        .css({
            position: 'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden'
        })
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/DmMZN/5/